# How to get user's id for openning a facebook-profile-page? (Android)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the user id for openning a facebook intent for a specific user. Someone have a n idea how to do this?
This is my problem:

```
  try{


        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/" + user_id));
        startActivity(intent);

        }catch(Exception e){

        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/UserNamePage")));
        }
```

My question is how do I get this user_id?

```
graphUser.getId();
```

This method is returning an incorrect user_id (The id it given from this code is different from the one that given in the link: https://graph.facebook.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s not an incorrect ID, it´s an "App Scoped ID", see the changelog for more information about that: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

You can´t get the real ID anymore since v2.0, and you can´t get the username/vaniy-url either. Which means, access to the profile is not possible anymore. This is for privacy reasons, i assume.

Now if you want to get the "timeline" of the user (meaning, his "feed"), you would need to authorize the user with the "read_stream" permission. But you will not get that one approved for an Android App, i am afraid. It will only get approved for "platforms without a native Facebook client" (Smart TVs, ...).

Comment: Thanks for replaying. Are you sure there is no other way for opening the facebook app on a specific profile?

Comment: yes, i am sure. there is no way to access the user profile url anymore. what you CAN do is get the profile picture of the user though, with that app scoped id: graph.facebook.com/app-scoped-id/picture - if you would be able to get the profile url of the user, the whole concept with the app scoped ids would be pointless ;)

Comment: Do you have a tutorial that explained how to  get the "timeline" of the user?

Comment: well, the facebook docs include everything you need: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/feed - but as i said, you would need to get "read_stream" approved, and facebook will not approve it for android apps.